# Laravel unnioAll between multi queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 3 queries in my laravel controller:

```
$data1=DB::table('tabl1')->where('brandid',$brandid)
                     ->select('id', 'name', DB::raw('sum(amount) AS SUM'))
                     ->get();

$data2=DB::table('tabl2')->where('brandid',$brandid)
                     ->select('id', 'name', DB::raw('sum(tax) AS SUM'))
                     ->get();

$data3=DB::table('tabl3')->where('brandid',$brandid)
                     ->select('id', 'name', DB::raw('sum(tax2) AS SUM'))
                     ->get();
```

I want to select the id, name and the sum of the 3 SUM using union between the 3 tables. I give up, any idea?

Comment: Is this your real code? Because having 3 tables about the same thing (as `'brandid'` seems to suggest) is such bad practice I don't know where to begin describing it...

Comment: example that can solve my problem, focusing on the problem

Comment: I think you can just call DB::select("... your query...");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
$data1=DB::table('tabl1')->where('brandid',$brandid)
                     ->select('id', 'name', DB::raw('sum(amount) AS SUM'));

$data2=DB::table('tabl2')->where('brandid',$brandid)
                     ->select('id', 'name', DB::raw('sum(tax) AS SUM'));

$data3=DB::table('tabl3')->where('brandid',$brandid)
                     ->select('id', 'name', DB::raw('sum(tax2) AS SUM'));

$data = $data1->unionAll($data2)->unionAll($data3);
$data = $data->get();
```

Didn't tested it but i think it should work

Comment: Have you removed each `get()` from `$data1`, `$data2` and `$data3`?

Comment: no, my mistake, now it's working ) thank you so much

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: sorry one more quesition about results, i'm trying to group result by id and name but it's not grouping, I know that because of the different SUM (fields), If it's possible to group the data by id and name, to get the sum for each id

Comment: Have you tried to group each query with those columns ($data1, 2 and 3)?

Comment: yes, in each query I grouped with the same fields then after union I grouped again. And now i tried to remove the sum to check if it's the problem, but same result.. no grouping

Comment: Please post new question with all details (data and expected result) to get proper help